# How to save php file as csv file?

Tags: php, string, csv, require-once

`script1.php` returns results:

```
helen,hunt
jessica,alba
```

`script2.php` returns results:

```
bradley,cooper
brad,pitt
```

`script.php` looks like this

```
<?php
echo "name,surname";
require_once('script1.php');
require_once('script2.php');
?>
```

and will return

```
name,surname
helen,hunt
jessica,alba
bradley,cooper
brad,pitt
```

**Question**

Maybe this is obvious to someone, but I am struggling for a while how to save this php file: script.php as csv file? script1.php and script2.php both produce result over while loop, so I would be able to save results as array inside of a while loop however hopefully someone will offer an easy solution to my original question.

Comment: You want to save it to a file on the server, or you want the user to download it?

Comment: *You want to save it to a file on the server, or you want the user to download it? – AbraCadaver 10 mins ago*

Comment: *I'll bet he's still waiting...* or is he? Edit: (ping) @AbraCadaver *are you?* ;-)

Comment: well newbie girl; question posted, answers given, see those. *Pretty fast, huh?* Bet you don't get fast service like that at a restaurant.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:  No, they are off to implement the first answer ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Well, I just got in now myself, but I won't be sticking 'round here to see the outcome; I already know what it is ;-) *ciao for now!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you are trying to save the output of those scripts to a CSV file.
Try doing:

```
ob_start();
echo "name,surname";
require_once('script1.php');
require_once('script2.php');
$result = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents('filename.csv', $result)
```

You can also take a look at fputcsv: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to do it having the access to the terminal, then just execute it

```
php -f script.php > file.csv
```

If you want to do it from the script, you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). It will be along the lines of:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "name,surname";
require_once('script1.php');
require_once('script2.php');
$size=ob_get_length();
if ($size > 0)
{
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    // save $content to file here
    ob_clean();
}
?>
```

Or, alternatively, if you can change `script1.php` and `script2.php`, make them open the file for appending (`fopen('fname.csv', 'a')`), and write to that file, it will result in rows from both of them written to the file without overwriting each other.

Comment: i dont see the point of echo then output buffering when you could just write to the file directly.

Comment: Presumably the question is "script1.php and script2.php are out of my control, and they already echo it, how do I print that to file"

Comment: I assumed _both produce result over while loop, so I would be able to save results as array inside of a while loop **however hopefully someone will offer an easy solution to my original question**_

Comment: @AbraCadaver: indeed. Put an alternative solution at the end, though it might not be how people actually do it in PHP.